# What will be the missing elements in this diet

Tags: nutrition, diet

I recently adopted following diet.

1. Green juice (Kale + Swiss Chard + Spinach + Blue Berry + Banana + Ginger) -Daily
2. Green juice (Bok choy + Collard green + Arugula + Cabbage + Broccoli + Garlic + Turmeric )
3. Oats (Old fashioned) - Daily
4. Steam rice cake and banana - Every night
5. Boiled egg - Alternative days
6. Avocado - 1 daily
7. Beans and lentils
8. Cacao for flavinoid
9. Asparagus
10. Apple/Prune

What are the essential elements that will be missing in this diet (for a 40 year old person)? Something like iodine? And what else?

Is there a need to add the following - barley / Brussels sprouts/ Flax seeds / macadamias / cashew? Also, Fenugreek(Uluva (in Malayalam)) and Cinnamon for blood sugar control?

Comment: It seems that this question is to answer a school assignment. Either that, or you are a 40 year old man trying to get the most out of your diet. I can't tell which.

Comment: Welcome to health SE :-). We cannot recommend a personalised diet on-line, there are many factors which influence what may or may not be necessary in your diet.

Answer (score 1):

Theres choline, but hey why not calculate it yourself? I can't share a website that does no sell anything too often it seems,but you will find on my profile.

The nutritional database are from Usda and websites transform their data with % value and tools to calculate total nutrient amount of selected foods.

From what I know you are missing several nutrients. Should also check for spinach oaxalic acid and nutrient interference, as well as uric acid impact.

You should try sunflower seeds,pumpkin seeds,peanuts, and look seeds/nuts and herbs you'll find everything(except iodine for usda) 
B12 can be supplemented (don't forget it's stored in the liver)

Answer (score 1):

You missed a lot actually!

- **Raw Honey** in lukewarm water , very first thing in the morning, great if lemon added to it.
- **Grapes(raisins)** drink it in the morning and the noon after soaking it in the glass of water if they are raisins or eat it raw.
- **Figs** (in many ways, eating, make a powder to clean teeth and drinking a tea of it by boiling it)
- **Olives** either as an oil or vegetable
- **Oranges** at least two daily, make a juice with its fiber and drink it sip by sip slowly.
- **Dates and Guava** (in the morning) are seen as the most nutritious.
- unbleached **Jaggery** a little piece after every meal.
- **Beetroot** especially if you have eye issues or anemia problem.
- **Almonds** either as an oil or eat it after soaking it at night and eating it very first things in the morning.
- **Cashew** has healing benefits.

Comment: Don't keep your honey and water mixed for long periods of time; however, it will ferment and possibly mold.

Comment: No, just add honey in lukewarm water and drink it instantly, it is not for storage, we never add honey to water to store it in Asia or our drinking water bottles, it is another thing to add it to the ayurvedic medicines. Thanks, I did not know this.

Comment: Yeah, I just wanted to make sure that no one tried making it and then storing it.